# Tool for analyzing VB6 source code (like Understand from SciTools)

Tags: vb6, code-analysis

Does anyone know of a tool to analyze/navigate VB6 source code like the tool from scitools?

http://www.scitools.com/products/understand/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VBDepend](http://www.vbdepend.com) is now available,it's NDepend like for vb6.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe [Project Analyzer](http://www.aivosto.com/project/project.html) is an alternative?
Also you could take a look at [codesmart 2009 for VB6](http://www.axtools.com/products-codesmart-vb6.php)

Answer (score 8):

- [Project Analyzer](http://www.aivosto.com/project/project.html)
- The free [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) plug-in for the VB6 IDE has some nice features, like listing all callers to the current procedure, and a much-improved search tool. **Get this**, even if you decide you need another tool for analysing.
- FKCoder [mentions in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004699/documenting-a-dependancy-tree/1008077#1008077) that Microsoft's free [Visual Basic 6.0 to Visual Basic .NET Upgrade Assessment Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=10C491A2-FC67-4509-BC10-60C5C039A272&displaylang=en) creates a call graph in HTML for a single VBP project.
- If you have Visio, you probably have the [Unified Modeling Language (UML) Reverse Engineering](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HP012088041033.aspx) add-in for VB6 that will create UML diagrams from your code.
- EDIT: +1 to [kb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177862/tool-for-analyzing-vb6-source-code-like-understand-from-scitools/1177938#1177938) for [CodeSMART for VB6](http://www.axtools.com/products-codesmart-vb6.php)

Comment: If you're working with VB6, you **WANT** MZTools, even if you don't know it yet....

Comment: Yeah, already using MZTools and also CodeHelper from PlanetSourceCode. Great tools.

Answer (score 1):

Our [SD Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) is a language sensitive tool for search across large bodies of source in VB6 (and it understands many other langauges, e.g, C, C++, C#, Java, COBOL, PHP, ... at the same time!).

It understands the structure of the langauge (identifiers, numbers, keywords, strings, operators, comments, whitespace) and lets you formulate queries for code constructs in terms of those entities.   Because it understands langauge structure, it is isn't fooled by whitespace changes or line breaks, and this significantly reduces the number of false positive hits.

The Source Code Search Engine preindexes your source code base to provide extremely fast searches even over millions of lines of code.   The Graphical UI shows hits on queries; from there, a single mouse click can show you the source code for hit.  From the souce code, you can go directly into most editors.

As a side effect of indexing the code base, the SCSE also computes various metrics per file: SLOC, NCSLOC, McCabe and Halstead complexity numbers, etc.

A unique kind of analysis the we offer for VB6 that is different than SciTools is [duplicate code detection](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone).