# VB6: create a code map?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have a pretty incredibly large VB6 program that I took over.  I have been on the job for a bit now, so this is nothing all that urgent.  But I recently ran a line counter on the code.  Over 1 million lines.  Most VB forms do a LOAD XXX to connect many projects.  Is there a way to map all this out?  So I can see the 5,000 or so projects all in one big map...

Comment: Like, as a graph or diagram? Maybe the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177862/tool-for-analyzing-vb6-source-code-like-understand-from-scitools/1178049) could satisfy you?

Comment: ooooo, thats it.  :-)  thanks a ton johnwait

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that as part of our [free assessment](http://www.gizmoxts.com/) we can perform this service for you, including an effective line count, map of connections between the different projects and an analysis of potential circular references that can arise from this late binding pattern.

I hope no one minds pointing out a free service...