# Dependency/NDepend type tools for VB6

Tags: vb6, dependency-management

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004699/documenting-a-dependancy-tree) talks about Vb6/.Net but all the answers address the .Net aspects but not the VB6 aspects.

Would anyone know of tools that allow a simillar kind of graphing/dependency try to be created for **VB6** apps. I assume that it would have be done from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [VBDepend](http://www.vbdepend.com/), never used it personally, but I believe it claims to meet your needs.

Also these questions might help:

- [VB6 project to UML diagram tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191287/visual-basic-project-code-to-uml-diagram-tool)
- [Tool like Understand for VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177862/tool-for-analyzing-vb6-source-code-like-understand-from-scitools)